# Dual Monitors of Same Type with Different Resolutions on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have two of the same type of monitor (HP Compaq LA2405x) attached to my Windows 10 laptop (HP Folio 9470m) via a docking station that has one display port and one VGA port.  When I try to set the resolution for the monitors, monitor A, which is connected using the display port, has a max/recommended resolution of 1920x1200. Monitor B, connected via VGA, has a max/recommended resolution of 1920x1080.

I was told by a colleague that VGA supports much higher resolutions than 1920x1080, so the lower max on B shouldn't be because of that.

Anyone know of other reasons why the resolutions could be different? I can't find anything in display or device settings.

Comment: Monitors are of the same brand? And which is their size in inches?

Comment: Both monitors are HP Compaq LA2405x (HP is the brand) and they are 24" (http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/pscmisc/vac/us/product_pdfs/HP_LA2405x_Datasheet.pdf)

Comment: This HP Support document is about connecting two monitors to the docking station [link](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c04123521).

Comment: VGA maximal resolution depends on several factors: [link](https://superuser.com/questions/527192/what-maximal-resolution-is-reasonable-when-using-a-vga-cable)